# Athena query: Access denied when writing to location: s3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a lambda function which runs a query in athena.

```
client = boto3.client('athena')

client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString="select * from table",
            QueryExecutionContext={
                'Database': DATABASE
            },
            ResultConfiguration={
                'OutputLocation': "s3://backet/prefix"
            }
        )
```

role to this labmda:

```
  CreateAthenaViewLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: '/'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAthenaFullAccess
```

but during execution, an error appears - Access denied when writing to location: s3://bucket/prefix/file.txt.
What I missed?

Comment: check on the bucket if there is an S3 Bucket Policy attached to it. Both should be allowed.